# How to create a safe copy of every new photo/video right after shooting?

Tags: backup, camera, automation

Is there any app that can secretly duplicate every photo/video right after it was taken?
Maybe using [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)?

Update:

I was thinking about this while reading a story about a journalist whose phone was taken by the politician's bodyguards when he was trying to film their illegal bahavior.

Comment: I just added 2 tags to your question to make your intention more clear -- as your point obviously is not "secretly duplicate", but rather "safely duplicate" (i.e. to a safe location), pointing to "backup and data safety" rather than to "spying at my partner" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That very much depends how and where you place the "secret", and what other conditions/restrictions are in place. Network storage (such as cloud services or email) e.g. require a network connection to be present, and the transfer might be noticed. A local copy might not have the copy-process noticed, but the copies could be found, in most times easily when using a file explorer. Your "secret act" might also indicate infringment on a 3rd persons privacy (if only your own photos are involved, then why the secrecy?), which not only would be indecent, but also may incur a penalty (no accusing, just a hint).

But assuming completely legal application, there might be a few options available:

- [photoCopy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.am.fi) backups photos to email. The app's description states: "when the program runs, there is no indication at all"
- [Photo Auto Uploader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrisstreeter.android.picasauploader) automatically uploads pictures to Picasa or Facebook after pictures are captured
- [Auto Uploader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aguilar.freeuploader) does the same for configured services
- [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) can synchronize your photo's folder (and of course others) periodically in the background -- to cloud services as well as to your home computer

There are more apps for each of the mentioned categories. There may also be some to create local copies, but I'm not aware of any at this time.

Comment: Thanks, will try them :) I've added the situation to the question.

Comment: Good idea, thank you! As said, I was not accusing -- just mentioning the fact, as people might think this the reason behind ;) But now it becomes quite clear; the word "secretly" was causing a bit confusion -- but secrecy was not your real point I see, rather "safely and automatically".

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken Dropbox automatically synchronizes all your photos as soon as you take them. I dont think there is an app that saves the photo in two places. What you can also do is set up a cron job every 5 minutes or so to copy new photos in another directory. 
Personally I think the Dropbox solution is better to do. On the other hand you can always create your own application to do so :)

Comment: Also G+ client does auto-upload of pictures (I don't know if it does it on videos also)

Comment: I've added the situation in question, please check it :)

Comment: I have Google+ and Dropbox, and all of my photos are automatically synced up with both my Google Photos and the "Camera Uploads" folder in my Dropbox. It works perfectly for photos taken with the stock camera, but I've had mixed results with other camera apps.

Answer (score 0):

Now there's also [Auto Backup](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2910392?hl=en&ref_topic=2907746) from Google.